# Need help omitting a ListNode from a Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

My objective here is to give the function "omit" an integer, and if that integer is in the "info" slot of on of the Nodes, that Node will be deleted. I understand what I have to do, just having a hard time executing it. Here is my ListNode inner class:

```
private int howmany;
private ListNode c;

private class ListNode {
    private int info;
    private ListNode link;

    public ListNode() {
        info = 0;
        link = null;
    }

    public ListNode(int i, ListNode pointer) {
        info = i;
        link = pointer;
    }
}
```

And here is the omit method that I tried:

```
public void omit(int i){

    ListNode pointer;
    pointer = c;
    if (pointer.info == i){
        pointer=pointer.link;
    }

    ListNode prev = pointer;
    ListNode curr = pointer.link;

    while (curr != null) {
        if (curr.info == i){
            prev.link = curr.link;
        }else{
            prev = prev.link;
            curr = curr.link;
        }
    }
```

This omit method just doesn't work. I tried it out in my client and the number that I try to omit stays in the list. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is c in the line `pointer = c`? shouldn't omit recive a list as an input?

Comment: c represents the collection of numbers in the list. The reason why omit isn't receiving a list as an input is because I want the user to input a number that's in the list, then that number gets deleted.

Comment: so you should upload the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you find a node where `curr.info == i`. In this case you do not modify `curr` leading to a infinite loop. Furthermore at the start of the list you skip at most one node, but there can be a arbitrary number of nodes that need to be ommited.

The best way to approach this is by iterating through the list and connecting a node that was not ommited with the last one not ommited:

```
public void omit(int i){

    // remove elements from the start of the list
    while (c != null && c.info == i) {
        c = c.next;
    }
    ListNode lastKept = c;
    ListNode current = c;
    while (current != null) {
        current = current.next;

        // find next node to be kept
        while (current != null && current.info == i) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        lastKept.next = current;
        lastKept = current;
    }
}
```